# Cordova iOS white bar at top

Tags: ios, cordova, webview

After adding StatusBarOverlaysWebview to config.xml, i get a white bar at the top of the screen and all the content is pushed down (see screenshot - there is a white bar on top of the statusbar). So instead of just adding the statusbar height (20px) to the screen, it adds 40px.

I double-checked all my styling and everything looks fine, so i guess its caused by the plugin somehow. Can anyone tell me how to solve this?

This is my config:

```
<preference name="StatusBarOverlaysWebview" value="false" />
<preference name="StatusBarBackgroundColor" value="#FF543E" />
<preference name="fullscreen" value="true" />
```

[image]

This is what it looks like without setting a color and using window.StatusBar.overlaysWebView(false); instead of config.xml

[image]

Comment: did the issue resolve?

Answer (score 5):

Try this, below code is working for me:

```
<preference name="StatusBarOverlaysWebView" value="false" />
<preference name="StatusBarBackgroundColor" value="#2D81C1" />
<preference name="Fullscreen" value="false" />
```

if you still have problem and if the same code was working for you in the previous builds, please check if plug in is installed and working properly

**Update**: For iOS 11 and iPhone X there are some changes in the library and HTML meta tags

In index.html change meta tag to this:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="viewport-fit=cover, width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
```

Please update ionic-angular library also for the latest devices support

More information here: [iOS 11 ionic checklist](http://blog.ionicframework.com/ios-11-checklist/)

Comment: I tried this with the statusbar plugin installed, and it did not fix the white bar problem.  I still see a white bar beneath the status bar above my app.

Comment: @SteveW I have updated the code for the latest version

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be a bug with the way Cordova handles iOS 11's statusbar.  As a fix, you can put

```
    <meta name="viewport" content="viewport-fit=cover">
```

in your index.html.

Comment: more information can be found here:http://blog.ionicframework.com/ios-11-checklist/

Answer (score 0):

**This Stuff is working for me in my app using Status Bar Plugin.**

`Try with below code.`

```
 <preference name="StatusBarOverlaysWebView" value="false" />
 <preference name="StatusBarStyle" value="lightcontent" />
 <preference name="StatusBarBackgroundColor" value="#FF543E" />
```

Comment: Yea, it worked for me a few days ago as well. StatusBarStyle doesnt change anything:/ When the app starts the statusbar looks fine, but is then immediately pushed down

Comment: @user3740962 So what is showing now the color which defined in code right ? Instead of white bar.

Comment: the color defined in StatusBarBackgroundColor is showing fine, but on top of that is a white bar. So its like the whole screen is pushed down 20px

Comment: @user3740962 is it happening when you tap and scroll down screen from the top ? can you post updated screen shot  ?

Comment: It happens in the process of launching the app, without any interaction. I posted a new screenshot

Comment: @user3740962 By default it will white top bar if you don't set color then how it will show that without white top bar. i think you need to force fully setup the color.

Comment: Setting the color is no problem. Check the screenshots - first one with color, second without. On both i get an extra 20px on top from setting StatusBarOverlaysWebView to false. So in the end i get 40px added to the top, where 20px is for the topbar as intended and the existing 20px is the white gap i highlighted on the screenshots

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110222/discussion-between-jaydroider-and-user3740962).

Comment: what were the output on that? I'm having the same problem. always have a white bar at the top of my application, looks like the webview is with a margin top 20px inside the app, not inside the html part

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:

**config.xml**
Add the below for statusbar:

```
<preference name="StatusBarBackgroundColor" value="#FFFFFF" />
```

**app.run.js**

```
if (window.StatusBar) {
  // cordova plugin org.apache.cordova.statusbar is used
  window.StatusBar.styleLightContent();
}
```

Comment: When i dont set overlaysWebView it all works fine, but setting overlaysWebView(false) in app.run gives me the same result

Comment: I am not sure what you mean here? Does the solution i have specified work or not?

Comment: It makes no difference if i put overlaysWebView(false) in app.run or in config.xml - i still get the "double" spacing in the top of the view. (check screenshot). But thanks for your suggestion

Comment: But I am using `styleLightContent()` and not `overlaysWebView(false)`. Where do you see `overlaysWebView()`?

Comment: My problem is about setting overlaysWebView to false - styleLightContent should only change the text-color of the statusbar and has nothing to do with this.. (i tried it though, just to be shure). Setting the color is no problem. As you can see on the screenshots - the first one i set the color and the second i dont set any color. on both of them there is an extra 20px on top

Answer (score 0):

I think you use OnsenUI so that will be the problem... Not the statusbar plugin. Try ons.disableAutoStatusBarFill(); to solve the problem  ;)

Comment: where did the original poster indicate they use OnsenUI?